# How to access constants defined in another apex class into the apex class in which we are working on?

Tags: apex

I have an apex class called Constants.apxc which is just meant for declaring constants. The value of these constants are Strings. These are some important and common values which can be reused across multiple apex classes. Currently I am working on another apex class in which I need to access the constants defined in that constants apex class file. How do I access it?

Comment: Did you try using `Constants.StringContactName` value

Comment: By the way, unlike other languages, a large Constants class will negatively impact your Apex performance. Consider custom labels, custom metadata, etc depending on your use case, or at minimum, use `public static DATATYPE VARNAME { get { return someValue; } }` to avoid the CPU penalty.

Answer (score 2):

By using dot notation, like you would with any other class method or variable.

Static variables are just `ClassName.StaticVariableName`
Instance (non-static) variables need an instance

```
MyClass classInstance = new MyClass();
system.debug(classInstance.instanceVariable);
```

And visibility modifiers obviously need to be set appropriately (i.e. you can't access a `private` variable outside of the class it's defined in)